# Rotating an image so it looks like it is spinning

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i am trying to rotate an image of a snowflake continuously so it gives the illusion of it spinning at the images centre, i'm struggling with this very much here is some code.

i have a loop where the function snowball is called but it just doesn't matter, because it doesn't rotate continuously just once.
Snow, is my image that i have brought in earlier in the code.

```
 function drawSnowBall() {
        context.beginPath();

        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            var p = particles[i];
            context.drawImage(Snow,p.x, p.y);
        }
        if (pause == false)
        {

        updateSnow();

}
    }
    var angle = 0;

    function updateSnow() {

        angle;

        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            var p = particles[i];
            //Updating X and Y coordinates
            //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards
            //Every particle has its own density which can be used to make the downward movement different for each flake
            //Lets make it more random by adding in the radius
            p.y += Math.cos(angle + p.d) + SnowSpeed + p.r / 2;
            p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;

            //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
            if (p.x > 800 + 5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > 700) {
                if (i % 3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
                {
                    particles[i] = {
                        x: Math.random() * 800,
                        y: -10,
                        r: p.r,
                        d: p.d
                    };
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just go with setInterval with your method inside and you are good.

Comment: Should probably use [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) instead